# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una calculadora de edad en python que el resultado sea en años, meses y días?

Tags: python

O sea, yo lo primero que hago es pedir la fecha actual (día,mes,año) al usuario y luego pido la fecha de su nacimiento(día, mes, año). Lo que quiero hacer es que la calculadora sea sencilla y que este con elementos básicos del python.

Gracias.

Codido de python:

```
from datetime import datetime

dia = input ("introdueix el día actual: ")

mes = input ("introdueix el mes actual: ")

any = input ("introdueix l'any actual: ")

dia_aniversari = input ("introdueix el día del teu aniversari: ")

mes_aniversari = input ("introdueix el mes del teu aniversari: ")

any_aniversari = input ("introdueix l' any del teu aniversari: ")

resultat = dia - dia_aniversari

resultat_mes = mes - mes_aniversari

resultat_any = any - any_aniversari

print ( "Tens", resultat_any, "anys", resultat_mes, "mesos", "i", resultat_dia, "dies")
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo te falta crear los objetos `datetime` con los datos que te introduce el usuario y efectuar la diferencia con la función `relativedelta` del módulo de python `dateutil`. Nota también que he agregado la función `int` a tus inputs para realizar la conversión de string a entero.

Te adjunto un ejemplo haciendo mínimas cambios en tu código:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dia = int(input("introdueix el día actual: "))
mes = int(input("introdueix el mes actual: "))
year = int(input("introdueix l'any actual: "))

today = datetime(year,mes,dia)

dia_aniversari = int(input("introdueix el día del teu aniversari: "))
mes_aniversari = int(input("introdueix el mes del teu aniversari: "))
any_aniversari = int(input("introdueix l' any del teu aniversari: "))

aniversari = datetime(any_aniversari,mes_aniversari,dia_aniversari)

resultat = relativedelta(today,aniversari)
print ( "Tens", resultat.years, "anys", resultat.months, "mesos", "i", resultat.days, "dies")
```

Puedes ahorrarte la parte de pedirle la fecha actual al usuario utilizando `datetime.today()`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dia_aniversari = int(input("introdueix el día del teu aniversari: "))
mes_aniversari = int(input("introdueix el mes del teu aniversari: "))
any_aniversari = int(input("introdueix l' any del teu aniversari: "))

today = datetime.today()
aniversari = datetime(any_aniversari,mes_aniversari,dia_aniversari)

resultat = relativedelta(today,aniversari)
print ( "Tens", resultat.years, "anys", resultat.months, "mesos", "i", resultat.days, "dies")
```

Como última observación te recomiendo no utilizar la palabra reservada `any` para nombrar tus variables.

Answer (score 0):

puedes manejar fechas como string y transformarlas a **Date** y utilizar relativedelta para que calcule el tiempo entre las dos fechas (Hoy - Aniversario)

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

now = datetime.datetime.now()
aniversary_str = input ("aniversary date (day-month-year): ")
aniversary_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(aniversary_str, '%d-%m-%Y')

rdelta = relativedelta(now, aniversary_date)
print(rdelta.years, "years", rdelta.months, "months", rdelta.days, "days")
```

Ejemplo:
`aniversary date (day-month-year): 01-01-2021`
resultado: `years 0 months 9 day 5`